# how to make draggable objects with mouseup/move?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i know how to make a draggable object in jquery with "mouseup/down/move", **but i can't figure how to do it for *multiple objects***.my main problem is how to select the object that i have clicked on.

here is my code for one object:

css

```
#hi {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-color: red;
position:absolute;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function(){
var click = false;
$('#hi').mousedown(function()
{
    click = true;
    console.log(click);
});
$('#hi').mouseup(function()
{
    click = false;
    console.log(click);
});

$(window).mousemove(function(e)
{
    if(click == true)
    {
        $('#hi').css('top',e.pageY);
        $('#hi').css('left',e.pageX);
    }
}); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="hi"></div>
```

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple done with jQuery UI : http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Keep you HTML and CSS, og use this JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#hi").draggable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery conveniently gives you the object that the user clicked on for all its mouse handling functions. The current scope (this) of the callback function is automatically set to that object.

Therefore, if you exchange your mousemove handler with this code here, it should do the trick:

```
$(window).mousemove(function(e)
{
    if(click == true)
    {
        $(this).css('top',e.pageY);
        $(this).css('left',e.pageX);
    }
});
```

Additionally, if you want a complete and easy-to-use solution for dragging objects, try jQuery UI's Draggable: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at The jQuery Draggable library: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/